# Error loading syntax file for Ruby Slim on Sublime Text 4

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, slim-lang

On latest Sublime Text 3 I get an error from Sublime Slim package everytime I launch ST3.
[image]
In the console I see this error.

```
unable to parse firstLineMatch "^#!/.*\b(node|js)$$?":target of repeat operator is invalid in regex ^#!/.*\b(node|js)$$?
warning: mnemonic t not found in menu caption Tools
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
unable to parse firstLineMatch "^#!/.*\b(node|js)$$?":target of repeat operator is invalid in regex ^#!/.*\b(node|js)$$?
```

I tried reinstalling the package but it didn't help.
Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Do you have a specific Ruby Slim file open when you launch Sublime? If so, what are the contents of that file? Also, by "*latest Sublime Text 3*", I'm assuming you mean Sublime Text 4? What build number do you have (**`Help → About Sublime Text`**)?

Comment: I believe this is fixed in the latest ST4 dev build

Comment: It's build 4121, it's ST4, sorry. Yes, I do have a slim file open when I launch ST4 and the file has a valid content. I can't show you the the content because it's too long.